# How to add a user exception to "Require pull request reviews before merging" option in git protected branch?

Tags: github, circleci

I am trying to use [lerna publish](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/publish#readme) to manage package publishing in my team. So what lerna does at the end of every publish is, it bumps the version in the `package.json` file and commits those changes in the branch that did the publish.

However in master I need `"Require pull request reviews before merging"` to be active as it is protected branch. [image: Require pull request reviews before merging]

My problem is not in publishing as lerna publishes the package. However the circle-ci fails with this error:

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/publish-test.
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
To github.com:username/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] publish-test -> publish-test (protected branch hook declined)
```

I tried enabling `"Restrict who can push to matching branches"` option to allow a user to commit in master, (we are using a bot user for devops commits). [image: Restrict who can push to matching branches]

Is there a way to add a user exception to the option `"Require pull request reviews before merging"` or do a pre-merge hook(so I can publish before the merge in ci)?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Or did you find a different solution?

Comment: Joining here, any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

### Update

GetHub enterprise now has the ability to create custom roles in which you can assign the permission to bypass branch policy.

---

The only way to excempt users is to make them repo admins and allow admins to bypass the policy.

Or use a GitHub actions workflow that uses the PAT if an admin to push to the target branch if the changes were pushed by allow-listed users. That opens up some interesting security issues though.

Answer (score 0):

Today people on the list "people and teams with push access" on the matching branch (as in your question) are still allowed to push to that branch even if you say "Require pull request reviews before merging" and, I approximate, "nobody can override the restrictions to merging".

Answer (score -1):

No there currently is no option for that but you could raise a feature request [here](https://support.github.com/contact/feedback). There probably is no way to work around the branch protection, which is pretty much the point of it.

On your second question: As far as I know, there is no specific "pre-merge" hook, here is the [list of all workflow triggers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows). You could work around this triggering at push for the branch you are merging to or could trigger on creating a release or maybe one of the [mentioned pull-request hooks](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) can enable your scenario.

Comment: You can trigger on the pull_request close event which works out to a pre-merge. You have to be careful about shas and such since a checkout in a pr effectively clones the base branch and merges the pr branch and that's what you have in a pr close event workflow.
A workflow in a push to base branch context will checkout to a new sha in the base branch.
Note that a failed workflow in a pr close context does not stop the pr from closing. I don't know of a way to do that.